# Determine current / own iframe

Tags: javascript, dom, iframe, dom-events, onload

What is the best way to determine the `iframe` DOM element a page is being displayed in ?

I need to notify the parent window when the iframe's contents have *really* finished loading (iframe `onload` looks like a scam with WebKit).

Consider the following scenario:

- Parent window loads a new iframe
- The loaded iframe invokes a function from the parent window and sends along a reference to its iframe DOM element (sort of a "sender" parameter).
- The parent's invoked function destroys the iframe.

Suggestions on alternative solutions to this inter-frame communication are also welcome.

One problem I faced was that Safari / Chrome / WebKit browsers apparently fire the iframe's `onload` event too early – I tried sending form data (with file upload) to an iframe and had the `onload` handler clear the `<input type="file" />` element's value and destroy the iframe, causing the form submission to be *aborted*, so I cannot use `onload` in that case (btw, is that a feature or a bug ?).

Another use case is where the iframe does something and wants interact with the parent.

Comment: what onload handler are you talking about? the iframes or the documents that you load in the iframe?

Comment: The iframe's `onload` handler.

Comment: if you can, try to set the onload function in the documents body tag and call from there up to the parent, that should work. I remmebr having seen the iffy webkit onlaod on iframes before and also rememebr a solution i built around it, but it's well oevr a year ago and i can't find the source code right now in our repository - if you truely need it, i can look for it :)

Comment: Thanks Martin, I don't really need it but I'm sure interested to hear about the workaround you've come up with, so let me know if you find it some day - no need to hurry though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like Stefaan id say `window.parent` but you should check [window.frameElement](http://help.dottoro.com/ljsokerh.php) too.

Comment: Looks like this is what I was looking for... seems to be supported by all major browsers although it is not part of any standard.

Comment: Isn't this the parent of the iframe, rather than the current iframe?

Answer (score 2):

With **window.parent** you can get the parent window. You can also call methods on it. So with the following code you can notifiy the iframe parent that you have finished loading (you need to have a notifyLoaded function in the parent window.

```
window.parent.notifyLoaded(window);
```

Because we gave our own window the parent can loop all known iframes and check which one is loaded (using *iframe.contentWindow* to get the window of a certain iframe)

Comment: Yeah, the solution with `contentWindow` scanning was the best I could think of... I was wondering if there was a better one, but it currently seems to be the only way to go.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to communicate between a frame and it's parent.

The easiest is if both have same `document.domain` set, in which case they can communicate directly.

if not there are several different ways of doing cross domain communication, for instance by setting/reading the hash-component of the iframe url

[Look here for more information](http://softwareas.com/cross-domain-communication-with-iframes)

Comment: This is good to know, but in my case, I do not need cross-domain communication - everything stays on one domain.

Answer (score 1):

You can walk all iframe-elements inside the parent document and compare the contentWindow-property of the iframe-elements with the window-object inside the iframe(should be equal, but I didn't test it yet)

P.S.: tested it now, works fine http://www.jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/CMdLZ/

Comment: I thought about the same solution but it is quite inefficient as it has to search for the iframe.

Comment: I'm afraid there is no other way than some kind of searching, as long as a window has no property to determine a parent DOM-element . Another solution may be to give the iframe-element an ID and submit the ID together with the form, so you can directly access the DOM-element using `parent.document.getElementById('submitted_ID')`